# How to return a variable from inside an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, arrow-functions

I am newbie to node and I am having hard time in getting a very basic thing.

```
    redis_client.get('foo', (err, reply) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(reply);
    });
    console.log(reply);
```

I want to access variable **reply** of line 3 in line 5. There is no issue till line 3.
A simple function instead of an arrow function will also work for me.

Comment: Assign the call and return reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a promise.

```js
export function getFromCache (key) {
  return new Promise((res, rej)=>{ 
     return redis.get(key, (err,data)=>{

          if (err) {
                return rej(err)
           }

           return res(data);
     });
  });
}
```

Comment: Since the OP is fairly new at this, you should probably show them how to use the returned promise.

Comment: Yes, I think that would be great. If told how to use the promise.